# Shadow in transparent background in blender 2.77 cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

I heard about shadow in newer version in blender 2.77 without any compositing and i don't how to do that,anyone tell me how to add shadow in transparent background in blender 2.77 cycles.

Comment: If you're referring to the shadow catcher material, that isn't in Cycles yet. See: https://developer.blender.org/D1788

Answer (score -1):

Try going in "Film" and check "Transparent" and make it Gaussian.[image: Transparent!]

Comment: That would make a transparent background, but not a "shadow catcher".